# Lag time for Sentinel-1 collection on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, copernicus

I tried to access the most recent image from COPERNICUS/S1_GRD collection on Google Earth Engine (GEE) but noticed that the latest available dates back to 15 days.

What is the lag time for S1 images availability on GEE?